# how to show div based on href of anchor tab lists in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple anchor tags and I want to match their `href` attribute. Based on the match a div should display. I have used the below code but it didn't work.

```
<div class="form-group search-form" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="abc.aspx">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="def.aspx">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="ghi.aspx">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
if ($("li a[href='abc.aspx']")) {                   
    $("input.search-form").css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: If the page is being transferred to `abc.aspx` on click, then the visibility of an element in the current page is pretty moot - the page is about to be destroyed

Comment: I am not clicking on that link just finding it, and working on master page.. want to show div

Comment: why negative voting for this question, if some body doesn't have answer then its not necessary to down vote..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$("li a[href = 'abc.aspx']")` would be always truthy since an object is a truthy value so instead check length property for checking it's existence. Although you can use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method to show a hidden element.

```
if ($("li a[href = 'abc.aspx']").length) {                   
  $("input.search-form").show();
}
```

---

More specific with [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method.

```
$("input.search-form").toggle($("li a[href = 'abc.aspx']").length > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all the `li a` elements and filter the elements according to `href` attribute with the `.attr("href")`. A check for the attribute value allows you to differ between the values. This also allows you, to use a defined list of URL strings (e.g. `['abc.aspx', 'def.aspx', ...]`) and create a generic solution, where you can loop through that list. Otherwise, for a generic solution, you would need to create concated Strings (`li a[href='abc.aspx']`), which is not that neat.

```
$("li a").each(function() {
   var href = $(this).attr("href");

   if(href === 'abc.aspx') {
       $("input.search-form").css('display', 'block');
   } else if(href === 'def.aspx') {
       $("input.search-form").css('display', 'block');
   } else if(href === 'ghi.aspx') {
       $("input.search-form").css('display', 'block');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am not clicking on that link just finding it

Using a jQuery object directly in an `if` condition will always equate to `true`. Hence you need to use the `length` property of the jQuery object to discover the number of found elements.

In your case you can use the `toggle()` method on the content to be shown, and check the `length` property of the selector for the relevant `a` element. Try this:

```
$('.input.search-form').toggle($("li a[href='abc.aspx']").length != 0);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/36fzhnjp/)